# inmobi javascript call ad twice

Tags: javascript, inmobi

According to inmobi Developer Wiki

http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript

You can call the Ads on Demand using manual: true parameter in the Var section:

E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js">
    </script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
  var inmobi_conf = {
    siteid : "your site id",
    slot : "slot number",
    test: true,
    manual: true
  };
</script>


<div id="adArea"> </div>
```

To generate the Ad you have to call it using:

```
_inmobi.getNewAd(document.getElementById('adArea'));
```

it should populate the Ad.

I´ve created a simple test example to request an Ad on demand (using test siteid provided by inmobi).

The problem is that I have to click twice to load the Ad

Full Source:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     var inmobi_conf = {
       siteid : "4028cba631d63df10131e1d3191d00cb",
       slot : "15",
       test: true,
       manual: true
     };

     function loadAdd(){
       _inmobi.getNewAd(document.getElementById('screen'));
   };
   </script>
   <script src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js"></script>        
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id="screen"> </div>
        <button id="btn1" onClick="loadAdd()">Load Ad</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can try it out on http://jsfiddle.net/YYzqA/

1st click on "Load Ad" button (no Ad)

2nd click on "Load Ab" button (the Ad will be loaded)

By chance do you know the reasons for this behavior? am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `manual: true`

you  need to set it to `manual: false` for it to automatically set the configuration for you.

When you set `manual: true`, your first click is loading the configurations

Checkout the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYzqA/1/)

Comment: thanks a lot it works now!  :) i could not find any documentation saying to set it to false! may inmobi should update the wiki.